# Why is this loop destroying my memory?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-mapped-files

I have this function in my MMF class

```
    void Clear() {
        int size = SizeB();
        int iter = size / sysInfo.granB;
        for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++) {
            auto v = (char*)MapViewOfFile(hMmf, FILE_MAP_READ | (write ? FILE_MAP_WRITE : 0), 0, i * sysInfo.granB, sysInfo.granB);
            std::memset(v, 0, sysInfo.granB);   
            UnmapViewOfFile(v);
        }
    }
```

So what it does is go through the whole file in smallest addressable chunks (64k in this case), maps the view, writes 0's, unmap, repeat. It works allright and is very quick but when I use it, there is some phantom memory usage going on.

According to windows task manager, the process itself is using just a few megabytes but the "physical memory usage" leaps up when I use it on larger files. For instance, using this on a 2GB file is enough to put my laptop in a coma for a few minutes, physical memory usage goes to 99%, everything in task manager is frantically reducing memory and everything freezes for a while.

The whole reason I'm trying to do this in 64k chunks is to keep memory usage down but the chunk size doesn't really matter in this case, any size chunks * n to cover the file does the same thing.

Couple of things I've tried:

1. flushing the view before unmapping - this makes things terribly slow, doing that 2gb file in any size chunks takes like 10 minutes minutes.
2. adding a hardcoded delay in the loop - it actually works really good, it still gets it done in seconds and the memory usage stays down but I just really don't like the concept of a hardcoded delay in any loop
3. writing 0's to just the end of the file - I don't actually need to clear the file but only to force it to be ready for usage. What I mean is - when I create a new file and just start with my random IO, I get ~1MB/s at best. If I open an existing file or force write 0's in the new file first, I get much better speeds. I'm not exactly sure why that is but a user in another thread suggested that writing something to the very end of the file after setting the file pointer would have the same effect as clearing but from testing, this is not true.

So currently I'm trying to solve this from the angle of clearing the file without destroying the computers memory. Does anybody know how to appropriately limit that loop?

Comment: @user81993 because these functions are not for working with files. `MapViewOfFile` loads entire file into your process memory and it's designed for different tasks. You need to use `CreateFile`, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`.

Comment: @user81993 Because you're using the functions and complaining about memory usage when you use large files. That suggests to me that you don't know what the functions actually do. If you can tell me what it is they _do_ and _how_, then I think you'd end up answering your own question

Comment: I think you two are the ones who need to read up on how they work, clearly I have the file and mmf handle prepared beforehand, clearly you can read the function arguments.

Comment: Rather than implying each other is stupid, why don't you tell us *why* you're using `MapViewOfFile` to read/write from a file, instead of the standard file I/O mechanisms.

Comment: I suspect zeroing the file with the regular file API before creating the mapping would be much faster. 2GB in 64 K chunks is ~30,000 mapView/unmapView operations on top of the I/O, and those are most likely not cheap.

Comment: Instead of using 64kb chunks, try to use really huge chunks such as 2Gb.

Comment: Can you output what the value that `MapViewOfFile` returns each time in the loop?  Why are you not checking for NULL being returned from that function?

Comment: @CodyGray It is in the post but to reiterate: random IO as in non sequential access is much faster with MMF's. I don't see how my choice of api is relevant to the question about using said api though.

Comment: You don't appear to be *doing* random I/O. You are looping through the whole file in 64-bit chunks. The choice of API is certainly relevant, you're asking a question about why it is behaving in a particular (undesirable) way and how to fix that problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie because I'm still prototyping the code and exception safety comes last, If the view mapping fails then I simply get a protected memory write exception but this is not the case here.

Comment: @user81993 why do you think random IO is faster with memory mapped files? Also, you are not _guaranteed_ to get a protected memory write exception. You are _guaranteed_ to invoke undefined behavior which _may_ be exhibited by a protected memory write exception.

Comment: @CodyGray MMF's are also generally as fast or faster in sequential than the more common IO methods, also this way I don't have to drop the mmf between clearings

Comment: So far there has been a lot of chatter but I see no reason this code should not work. I have not seen any productive comment so far. Maybe someone should point out why this is not supposed to work?

Comment: @usr the code does in fact work but produces undesirable effects on the system as described in the post.

Comment: @user81993 you _are_ dropping the MMF between iterations of the loop though...

Comment: @user81993 I understand that and I want to know the answer, too. Nobody has made an attempt at that yet.

Comment: @inetknght no, I'm dropping the view, there is a difference

Comment: Just because you unmap the view, there's no reason for the system to remove that page from physical memory. Why would it waste time doing that? Your code is a total disaster from a memory caching perspective. I see no reason at all for you to use memory mapped files to zero memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is it a common thing for the OS to become overwhelmed with this pattern? The OS is at liberty to remove old pages at any time. I see no reason why this code would monopolize physical memory usage (at least >= Vista. XP did that).

Comment: The lack of error checking is also going to burn you at some point.

Comment: @usr I expect that it depends on how much memory there is. I would expect the system to keep those pages in physical memory and kick pages out from other programs. Which may lead to swapping.

Comment: @David All that is nice and well (and even desirable). But clearly the system cannot cope (hence the question) and the resulting memory pressure *should* cause the system to remove these pages from physical memory. Failure to do so sounds like a pretty serious performance bug in the system’s memory handler, *unless* somebody can explain why this usage pattern is rightly not anticipated by the system — which brings us back to the actual question of the OP. Nothing I can see in the documentation (or that I can remember from my use of MMFs) suggests that this is reasonable behaviour.

Comment: @user81993 can you try this with a single view? Maybe the frequent view creation triggers bad behavior in the OS. What OS is this even?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I posit that the asker's program monpolises physical memory. Which leads to other programs having discardable pages kicked out to swap. Which leads to disk thrashing and the symptoms reported. The system isn't going to kick out the pages that have just been memory mapped. It's going to kick out pages that were accessed less recently.

Comment: And that should not happen. It is my understanding that mapped files and cached reads/writes use exactly the same page cache. If it's OK to ReadFile through an entire file it should be OK to use MMF for that as well. In fact, MMF's are *specifically made* for huge file scenarios.

Comment: @usr The OS is win7 sp1. My laptop only has 3gb of ram so I can't create a 2gb view, I can do 4x512mb ones reliably enough but this causes the same issue.

Comment: You should be able to create a 1TB view on your machine provided it's a 64 bit process.

Comment: Does this "The Old New Thing" article offer you perhaps alternate methods of creating your large files? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150710-00/?p=45171

Comment: @usr I'm compiling for 32bit, in there I get 87:"invalid parameter" when trying to create a view too big. I tried switching to 64 bit but the project is dependent on some libraries that don't like it and I can't get into that right now.

Comment: You are generating dirty RAM pages at a very high rate, 2 gigabytes worth of them.  They are not usable for anything else until their content has been written to the file.  A typical laptop spindle drive is pokey, you're lucky to get 2 MB/sec, so keeps the drive busy for 15 minutes.  The OS has to deal with a rather low amount of RAM while this goes on, it is in turned forced to unmap other RAM pages and has to write them to the paging file.  The disk drive is now seeking back-and-forth, very bad for speed.  You need to buy more RAM.

Comment: @HansPassant not an option, this needs to fit inside 128MB of ram in the end and deal with files much larger than 2gb.

Comment: @usr Ok, I ended up going for 64bit after all and the result is the same, single view covering the 2gb and as soon as memset starts, my laptop dies in agony. This changes things though, from what I remember, didn't mmf views used to consume memory (like in the obvious way rather than in the background phantom way)? I didn't think I could create views bigger than I had available ram, this means pretty big changes to my current program and the issue becomes even more important since I need a way to make sure this doesn't happen under other types of usage too.

Comment: @user81993 all that a memory map of a file does is _basically_ change page backing from the "normal" operating system swap file to, instead, the file that you specify. It then associates a memory range _to_ that file. It does not "swap-in" the data until you first access it, and doesn't swap-out the data until you ((flush) OR (memory stress is reached) OR (unmap AND operating system lazily writes)).

Comment: So with that in mind, if you have a 64-bit addressable memory, a 40-bit-size file, and memory map the _whole_ file, but only have 35-bits of memory, the _whole_ file is _addressable_, but accessing (read/write) _may_ incur swap characteristics

Answer (score 1):

So here's the thing. When you `MapViewOfFile`, it allocates the associated memory range but *may* may mark it as swapped out (eg, if it hasn't already been read into memory). If that's the case, you then get a page fault when you first access it (which will then cause the OS to read it in).

Then when you `UnmapViewOfFile`, the OS takes ownership of the associated memory range and writes the now-not-accessible-by-userspace data back to disk (assuming, of course, that you've written to it, which marks the page as "dirty", otherwise it's straight up deallocated). To quote [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366882(v=vs.85).aspx) (that I asked you to read in comments): `modified pages are written "lazily" to disk; that is, modifications may be cached in memory and written to disk at a later time.`

Unmapping the view of the file *is not guaranteed to "un-commit" and write the data to disk*. Moreover, even `CloseHandle` does not provide that guarantee either. It merely closes the handle to it. Because of caching mechanisms, the operating system is entirely allowed to write data back to disk on its own time if you do not call [FlushViewOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366563(v=vs.85).aspx). Even re-opening the same file *may* simply pull data back from the cache instead of from disk.

Ultimately the problem is

1. you memory map a file
2. you write to the memory map
3. writing to the memory map's address range causes the file's mapping to be read in from disk
4. you unmap the file
5. unmapping the file "lazily" writes the data back to disk
6. OS *may* reach memory stress, sees that there's some unwritten data that it can now write to disk, and forces that to happen to recover the physical memory for new allocations; by the way, because of the OS lazily flushing, your IO is no longer sequential and causes spindle disk latency to drastically increase

You see better performance when you're sleeping because you're giving the OS the opportunity to say "hey I'm not doing anything... let's go ahead and flush cache" which coerces disk IO to be roughly sequential.

Comment: What you are saying is that the OS is allowed to behave in the way observed. Nobody has contradicted that. It's just surprising that the OS totally screws up in this situation and makes the machine unusable. Overwriting an entire mapped file front-to-back seems like an ordinary use case. I don't see why unmapping a file/view would cause/force lazy flushing, either (this answer implies that). And even if it did, why wouldn't it be sequential?

Comment: Stackoverflow comments are not a good location for discussions. Nonetheless... overwriting an entire mapped file front-to-back is _not_ a typical use case _for memory mapping files_. When you want to overwrite a file front-to-back without regard to what's in it, you use `WriteFile`. If you want to _read what's in the file and then overwrite the data_ then that _may_ be a use case for memory mapped files.

Comment: ...you don't see why unmapping a view of a file would cause lazy flushing? _The operating system documentation tells you so!_ Would you rather _wait_ for `UnmapViewOfFile()` to flush? Why wait for that? If you wanted to flush, you _should_ have been a little more explicit by using `FlushViewOfFile()`.  Otherwise the operating system is introducing an unnecessary wait. Maybe you were done with IO and you have more processing to do which doesn't have anything to do with files? Why make your application _wait_ in that situation?

Comment: I'm questioning the idea that step 5 is likely to happen and/or that is has anything to do with the problem. (I'm also not the OP.) Unmapping anything should not affect the lazy write policy of the OS in any way. The OS can flush at any time, regardless of whether the memory is mapped or unmapped.

Comment: It won't be sequential IO for two reasons. Firstly, you're already trying to read some location that's many blocks past wherever the OS has decided to flush. Secondarily, the OS does not make a guarantee that it flushes dirty blocks sequentially.

Comment: The OS does not guarantee sequential flushing but it would be stupid not to. It is clear that *almost nothing* is guaranteed here. The question is: Why does the OS behave so badly in the face of a common scenario. (I understand you think this is uncommon but I doubt it). The random IO caused by simultaneous reading and writing seems a plausible explanation, though.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. The OS can flush _at any time_. Which, if memory is not being stressed, why flush? Things work faster by giving IO bandwidth to things the user specifically needs to wait on and instead holding onto dirty pages in cache until such time as userland is idle (such as sleeping). Once memory becomes stressed, _then_ a requirement exists to clear out some memory so that processing can continue.

Comment: I agree that it would be smart for the OS to flush sequentially. But even if it does flush sequentially, you're still reading a block far in advance of wherever it's flushing.